# JWT token seems to be changing between "before all" and first test in Cypress

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

I am running the following test on Cypress

```
before(() => {
      cy.horizonAuth()
      cy.log(sessionStorage.getItem('JWT'))
    });

//API requests

    it('Sending a regular API request to Welcome Messages', function() {
        cy.log(sessionStorage.getItem('JWT'))
        cy.request({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/api/v1/organisations/welcome-message?actions=api/v1/organisations/welcome-message/set-welcome-messages',
            body : {"welcome_messages":[{"message":"<p>Test investor welcome message!</p>","type":"User"},{"message":"<p>Token from storage </p>","type":"Internal User"},{"message":"<p>Test entrepreneur welcome message!</p>","type":"Entrepreneur"}]},
            auth: {bearer: sessionStorage.getItem('JWT')}

    })
})
```

This is the auth command I am using

```
Cypress.Commands.add('horizonAuth', () => {
    let config = Cypress.config();
  
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: Cypress.config('tokenUrl') + '/api/v1?actions=api/v1/login',
      body: {
        username: config.horizon.username,
        password: config.horizon.password,
      }
    }).then(response => {
        cy.setLocal
      window.sessionStorage.setItem('JWT', response.body['api/v1/login'].token)
    })
  })
```

I noticed that my tests were failing the first time I ran the above, but if I ran the test a second time and commented out the `cy.horizonAuth()` then the test would pass. I decided to add the log commands to see the JWT token and it appears that the token is changing between the `horizonAuth` and the first test. This happens if I close the session and start a new session also as the first time it's run the Log comes back with "Null"

[image: First time tests are run in session]
[image: Second time tests are run in session]
[image: Third time tests are run with horizonAuth commented out]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I am fairly new to Cypress.

Comment: hey Dan, I'm wondering what is `cy.setLocal` from your `horizonAuth ` custom command? It seems superfluous..

Comment: Hi @AlexIzbas , yes I noticed this after I posted the question this morning, I have no idea how that line of code got there but it has been removed now (I think it was a case of me trying something but it not working and then not removing the entirety of what I had tried), but unfortunately it made no difference to my problem.

Comment: `Cypress.Commands.add('horizonAuth', () => { let config = Cypress.config();
  
   return cy
  .request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: Cypress.config('tokenUrl') + '/api/v1?actions=api/v1/login',
    body: {
      username: config.horizon.username,
      password: config.horizon.password,
    }
  }).then(response => {
   window.sessionStorage.setItem('JWT', response.body['api/v1/login'].token)
   return cy.wrap(response, { log: false });
  })
  });` 

and try to run again
(p.s. sorry for the above formatting)

Comment: On first run you get null value as your `.then(response => {` callback is not done yet at the moment you call for it. Let's try to make sure it executed immediately by adding a return statement in the command body. See above comment

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AlexIzbas I have tried the above but unfortunately the same outcome occurs, two separate JWT tokens with a 401 unauthorised error on the first test, but once `cy.horizonAuth()` is commented out the request in my first test runs fine.